# proof of combinatorial identity using given identities

Tags: combinatorics

How does one prove $$\sum_{v} (-1)^v \binom {a} {v} \binom {n-v} {r}=\binom {n-a} {n-r}$$ where $n,r$ are positive integers, $a$ is arbitary real ,

using the given two identites.
$$  \binom {-a} {v}=(-1)^v\binom {a+v-1} {v}         $$where $a>0$ is real 
and $$\binom {m} {0}\binom {l} {r}+\binom {m} {1}\binom {l} {r-1}+....\binom {m} {r}\binom {l} {0}=\binom {m+l} {r}$$

where $m,l$ are arbitary numbers and $r$ is a positive integer. 
$$ $$I have been trying for a long time now. I can prove it using comparing degrees of certain terms in polynomials. But I don't see a way using the given identities.

Comment: Are you sure that $\binom {-a} {v}=(-1)^v\binom {a+v-1} {v}$ for $a>0$?

Comment: @Monadologie Yes, isn't it?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @ Monadologie yes. Its from Feller vol 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{\nu}}&\color{blue}{ (-1)^{\nu}\binom{a}{\nu}\binom{n-\nu}{r}}\\
> &=\sum_{\nu} (-1)^{\nu} \binom{a}{\nu}\binom{n-\nu}{n-\nu-r}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^{n-r}\sum_{\nu} \binom{a}{\nu}\binom{-r-1}{n-\nu-r}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^{n-r}\binom{a-r-1}{n-r}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n-a}{n-r}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we use the *[Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*
  $\sum_{\nu}\binom{p}{\nu}\binom{q}{n-\nu}=\binom{p+q}{n}$.
- In (4) we use again the binomial identity as we did in (2).

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @jnyan: You're welcome.